# ios Swift XLForm - Conform to Protocol XLFormOptionObject

Tags: ios, swift, xlform

I'm trying to to conform to this protocol in swift

**Protocol**

```
@protocol XLFormOptionObject <NSObject>

@required

-(NSString *)formDisplayText;

-(id)formValue;

@end
```

**My Class which should conform to this protocol**

```
@objc (myclass)
class myclass : XLFormOptionObject{

     var formDisplayText: NSString {
        return self.name
    }
    var formValue: AnyObject {
        return self
    }
}
```

**Comment**

As per my understand i should change id with Anyobject, but the XCode 6.1 is still give me compiler error - Class dose not conform to protocol

**Question**

Any suggestions how to conform to protocol with A pointer to an instance of a class "id"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue isn't the `formValue()` func, but rather the `formDisplayText()` func. You must force unwrap the string. It's not clear to me why this is required since the return value is clearly not an optional, but if you look at how swift converts objc method calls for bridging you'll notice that it will almost always reinterpret method return values as forced unwrapped.

```
//MARK: - XLFormOptionObject
func formDisplayText() -> String! {
    return self.status
}

func formValue() -> AnyObject {
    return self.ID
}
```